# Игнорируется метод continueWithTask()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

По нажатию кнопки берется фото из галереи (метод `addPhoto`), в методе `onActivityResult` фото загружается в Firebase Storage с названием полученного ключа.

Затем [согласно документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0#get_a_download_url), для получения URL картинки используется метод `continueWithTask`, внутри которого полученный URL кладется в Firebase Database.

Проблема: метод `continueWithTask` не запускается (проверял логами + он значение URL остается null). В чем ошибка или как еще можно вернуть из метода URL (переменная типа Uri)?

Код:

```
public void addPhoto(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

            final DatabaseReference newDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items").push();

            donosId = newDatabaseReference.getKey();

            final StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/" + donosId + ".jpg");

            imageRef.putFile(data.getData()).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                        String var = downloadUri.toString();

                        Item item = new Item(mNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                                mSecNameEditText.getText().toString(), var,
                                (int) System.currentTimeMillis());
                        newDatabaseReference.setValue(item);

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Сам файл появляется в firestorage?